# Mostrar DateTimeOffset con formato C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Quiero imprimir en un excel la fecha datetimeoffset, pero intento darle un formato en el ToString()

aqui el fragmento de codigo

```
`public async Task<ApiResponse<string>> ExportAsync(FilterGrid filter)
        {
            object objectMultiple = await this.unitOfWork.ActivityRepository.GetAsync(filter.GetProperties());
            var records = (IEnumerable<Activity>)objectMultiple.GetType().GetProperty("records").GetValue(objectMultiple);
            var dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
            using (var woorkbook = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                string base64 = woorkbook.GetExcelFromEnumerableModel<Activity>(records, filter.Columns,
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SheetName) ? "Reporte" : filter.SheetName,
                    new Dictionary<string, System.Func<Activity, string>>
                {
                        { "ID", (data) => { return data.IdActivityParent == null ? data.ID.ToString() : string.Empty; } },
                        { "activo", (data)=> { return data.Active ? "Activo" : "Inactivo"; } },
                        { "datetime1", (data) => { return data.DateTime1.HasValue ? data.DateTime1.ToString(dateFormat) : string.Empty; } },
                        { "datetime2", (data) => { return data.DateTime2.HasValue ? data.DateTime2.ToString() : string.Empty; } },
                        { "datetime3", (data) =>{return data.DateTime3.HasValue ?  data.DateTime3.ToString() : string.Empty; } }

                });
                return new ApiResponse<string>(base64);
            }
        }`
```

Intente hacer una variable de dateFormat, pero me marca error
`Error  CS1501  Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'ToString' toma 1 argumento`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un nulleable DateTime `Datetime?`, el cual su función `ToString()` no tiene argumentos, debes usar el `Value` para rescatar un `DateTime` NO nulleable

```
 { "datetime1", (data) => { return data.DateTime1.HasValue ? data.DateTime1.Value.ToString(dateFormat) : string.Empty; } },
```

Un detalle, el return no es necesario

```
 { "datetime1", data =>  data.DateTime1.HasValue ? data.DateTime1.Value.ToString(dateFormat) : string.Empty; },
```

Comment: Por que no es necesario el return?

Comment: @karlDomínguez Es una característica de las lamba expression (arrow function en otros lenguajes), si sacas el `return` y los `{}`, el return es implícito (ya que un Func siempre tiene return), es solo para que el código quede más limpio (en otros lenguajes es igual, javascript y php por ejemplo). Hace una cuantas versiones atrás de .net esto lo hizo extensivo para las "funciones normales", ahora esto es válido: `public int GetValor() => 2`  (esta función retornará 2). Recuerda aceptar tu respuesta si te ha ayudado, saludos

Comment: @karlDomínguez Porque en una función de flecha (o expresión lambda) las llaves se usan si el cuerpo de la expresión es de más de una línea. Sin las llaves, es una expresión de una línea y asume que el resultado de la expresión es el valor devuelto de forma automática. Para usar `return` debes colocar las llaves, ya que el cuerpo de la expresión pasa a ser un bloque, en vez de una línea, y ahí si debes indicarle dónde devolverá el valor.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :D